# Sharepoint : Fire Jquery after upload document library

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to sharepoint development and my task is to hide certain columns in a document library I managed to do it with jquery but the problem when I add a document to my library the jquery does not activate and the columns will be unmasked again Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide columns in document library list view, we just modify the list view and uncheck the columns in this list view.

[Show or hide columns in a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-or-hide-columns-in-a-list-or-library-b820db0d-9e3e-4ff9-8b8b-0b2dbefa87e2)

If you just want to use jQuery to achieve it. The following code for your reference.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() { 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function (ctx) {
            //add column name 
            var columns=["column1","column2"];
            //hide columns
            hideColumns(columns);
        }
    });
});
function hideColumns(columns){  
    for(var i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
        var columnIndex=0;
        $(".ms-listviewtable>thead>tr>th").each(function(index){ 
            if($(this).text().indexOf(columns[i])!=-1){
                columnIndex=index;
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
        $(".ms-listviewtable>tbody>tr").each(function(i){
            $(this).children("td").eq(columnIndex).hide();
        });
    }
}
</script>
```